# Delete "x" on dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio

Every time I use "write.table", I always get the data I need but with a "x" at the very beginning of the file (once it is exported). Does anyone knows how to delete it?

```
write.table(f, file = "Test.txt", row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "a "x" at the very beginning of the file (once it is exported)"? I don't see any "x" in a file written with `write.table".

Comment: Strange, this doesn't happen to me when I type, e.g. `write.table(mtcars, file = "mtcars.txt", row.names = FALSE)`. Maybe there is smth in your data (I suspect 'x' is just one of the colnames).

Comment: I had some hidden data, I didn't realise until now. Anyway thank you for the help!

Comment: Do you mean the column names? If they start with a number, R add them a X before to consider them as names instead of numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My idea, you don't give names to your columns
try this

```
write.table(f, file = "Test.txt", row.names = FALSE,col.names=FALSE)
```